# jsPDF upgrade from 1.5.3 to 2.5.1 don't work

Tags: jspdf

I use the jsPDF version 1.5.3 (jspfd.min.js downloaded and saved) and it works fine for every years. Yet i have tested the version 2.5.1 (jspfd.min.js downloaded and saved from unpkg). This gives the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined`. This is not possible because the variable/function is definitely present. With version 1.5.3 this error should otherwise also appear, but this is not the case. When (with 2.5.1) i call in the Firefox console the variable `jsPDF` it changes automatically to `jspdf` and display an object. Call really `jsPDF` it ist the error. When i change the name in my script from `new jsPDF` to `new jspdf` it gives the error: `Uncaught TypeError: jspdf is not a constructor`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are some breaking changes in version 2.0.0.

> We also changed the name of the global variable to jspdf (lower case)
> when using script tags to be consistent with the new es modules format
> and named imports/exports.

Adding the following line should work for backward compatibility:

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF
```

You need to import the module as follows:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
```

For other module formats, take a look at the repo doc directly: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF, ex.:

```
// Node.js
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf");

// Globals
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
const doc = new jsPDF();

// ...
```

Comment: Ok. thanks. `window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;` works. But yet i have another problems. For that i will open new questions. But, i unterstod it. On Github is written `const doc = new jsPDF({})`. And how i change my script for working so with this?

Comment: @Andramox Indeed, it depends on how you're running it, module type, format etc. you're using, so yeah, I think that deserves another question (that I am not sure to be able to answer). I suggest you post some of your code, if possible a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also if this answers helps, please consider accepting it by [checking the check mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Oh yeah, the rework on Stack... . For an another problem, there was a solution online. But for the next another problem i have open a new question. You find it over the tag.

Comment: yet i have realised the upgrade! this is needed for me: `var { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;`. insert before `doc = new jsPDF();`.