# jsPDF not defined with newer version of jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

In [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExddjxR?editors=1011) codepen I'm trying to convert a small html table to pdf using jsPDF but getting jsPDF not defined. I ensured I am importing the jsPDF library as well as jQuery but still getting error. I am using the same code as [another](https://codepen.io/REMCOOLE/pen/xxOGoKo) codepen where it works. I am using a newer version of jsPDF. How can create the pdf using the newer version? Thank you.

```
// js
$('.cmd').click(function () {  
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
  };
  var $addr = $(this).closest('.res').find('.content');
  var $temp = $('.content-template');
  $temp.find('h3').text($addr.find('h3').text());
  pdf.fromHTML($temp.html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers':specialElementHandlers
        }
  );
  pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
});

// html
<div class="container">
  <div class="res">
    <div class="content">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Semester</th>
        <th scope="col">Grade</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>May - August</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>September - December</td>
        <td>Distinction</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <button class="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a duplicate of [jsPDF upgrade from 1.5.3 to 2.5.1 don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820359/jspdf-upgrade-from-1-5-3-to-2-5-1-dont-work)

There were some breaking changes going from jsPDF v1 to v2, and unfortunately the official documentation is a bit lacking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

in jspdf 2.5.1 it is instantiated as follows: (**new jspdf.jsPDF**)

```
var pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF('p', 'in', [8.5, 12.9]);
```

I had to update to use it with html2canvas and at the beginning I had problems instantiating jspdf.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of jsPDF changed between Major Versions as you point out but the solution in this case is simply "Double Up" by either starting with

```
function generatePDF() {
  var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF('l')
```

or remove the first word and use

```
jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

function generatePDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('l')
```

or use

```
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

function generatePDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('l')
```

each may have limits in different set-ups but all 3 work in the [OP codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExddjxR?editors=1011) as seen here.

[image]